# Returning dynamic array through void function in C

Tags: c, malloc, return, void

In my C program, I use a void function with the following arguments:
One 2D int array, one int pointer that will be used to create the new dynamic array and a last int pointer which will hold a number of counts that will occur inside the function.
So the dynamic array is created in the function using malloc and everything works okay, until I print its elements in main() after calling the function. What I get is rubbish instead of the numbers I should see. Here's the function code:

```
void availableMoves(int array[][3], int *av, int *counter)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] == E)
            {
                printf("%d ", 3*i + j + 1);
                (*counter)++;
            }
        }
    }
    av = (int *) malloc(*counter * sizeof(int));
    if (av == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=0; i<*counter; i++)
            *(av + i) = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<3; j++)
            {
                if (array[i][j] == E)
                {
                    *(av + pos++) = 3*i + j + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just commenting on code: Since you have an error case, you should not modify `*counter` like that in error case. Use a temp `int tmp_count = *counter;` variable, and assign it back to `*counter` only if function succeeded. Alternatively, make it `abort();` if malloc fails, or something. Avoid producing "partial" result (`av=null` but `*counter` is still modified).

Comment: Try to understand pointer-dereference and indexing. `*(av + pos++) = 3*i + j + 1;` is the same as `av[pos++] = 3*i + j + 1;`, but most human readers prefer the second form. Similar for `(*counter)++;` which could be written as `*counter += 1;`, avoiding the parentheses.

Comment: @hyde: You're right, but that was a quick check of malloc, I'm not done with it yet. :)

Comment: @wildplasser: Is there something wrong with the parentheses?

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with them. But most people tend to reduce the number of parentheses, just because it is easier to read with fewer ((.)(.)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function, `av` is a pointer passed by copy. So when you change the value of your pointer inside the function, the original pointer won't be modified.

There are two possibilities :

- use a pointer to pointer (`int **av`);
- return the allocated pointer (`return av`).

So either:

```
void availableMoves(int array[][3], int **av, int *counter);
```

Or:

```
int *availableMoves(int array[][3], int *av, int *counter)
```

And the call:

```
availableMoves(array, &av, &counter);
av = availableMoves(array, av, &counter);
```

Comment: Third (IMO most consistent) approach would be to return boolean value: return true when both `av` and `counter` have been successfully modified, otherwise return false and leave `av` and `counter` unmodified.

Comment: @hyde: Could be indeed a good idea to use the return value otherwise.

Comment: Decided to use the first approach and it seems to be working! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

use  double pointer for your dynamic array `int **av` instead of `int *av`

```
void availableMoves(int array[][3], int **av, int *counter)
```

and into the function change `av` by `*av`